# How to add to a serialized array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization

I have an existing user which has a serialized field and I want to be able to add recent messages to the array / serialized field.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 serialize :recent_messages
end
```

In the controller I've tried

```
@user = current_user
@user.recent_messages << params[:message]
@user.save
```

but I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass):
```

In my schema I have:

```
create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.text     "recent_messages"
  end
```

Any ideas on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: For reference: you can look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45066671/how-can-i-get-rails-to-automatically-populate-a-dynamically-generated-form/45067018#45067018 for building forms that behave well with respect to arrays

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can pass a class to [`serialize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-serialize):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :recent_messages, Array
end
```

The above ensures that `recent_messages` is an `Array`:

```
User.new
#=> #<User id: nil, recent_messages: [], created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Note that you might have to convert existing fields if the types don't match.

Answer (score 2):

It's because the first time you try to push an item to your `recent_messages`, there's no array to push the item into (the field is `nil` by default). So you must create the array before you can push to it

```
@user = current_user
if @user.recent_messages.nil?
  @user.recent_messages = [params[:message]]
else
  @user.recent_messages << params[:message]
end
@user.save
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try following code:- By default `@user.recent_messages` would be nil

```
@user.recent_messages ||= []
@user.recent_messages << params[:message]
@user.save
```