# How to limit an array's size during push and pop

Tags: ruby, arrays, stack

I want to be able to store a users last 5 comments so I've created an array and am able to add comments to the array using:

```
comments << message
```

I only want the last 5 comments. Is there a simple way (setting the arrays size so the 6th one falls off) to achieve this without writing a method or storing every single comment and then only showing the last 5?

Comment: If the comments are fetched from a database, then fetching only 5 would be much quicker and easier to implement. Any reason why that won't work?

Comment: I don't want to store every comment because it will use up space and old comments aren't necessary. I only want to keep and display the last 5.

Comment: @spuggy why can't you solve your problem in this way : `if array.size > 5 then dont add a comment into this array end` ?

Comment: @spuggy Or, assuming you get those comments from a database, yuo could do something like that : 
`comments = Comments.find(:all, :conditions=> {whatever}).last(5)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own datastructure that wraps the functionality of an Array in ruby quite easily:

```
class CommentQueue

  include Enumerable

  def initialize(num = 5)
    @size = num
    @queue = Array.new
  end

  def each(&blk)
    @queue.each(&blk)
  end

  def pop
    @queue.pop
  end

  def push(value)
    @queue.shift if @queue.size >= @size
    @queue.push(value)
  end

  def to_a
    @queue.to_a
  end

  def <<(value)
    push(value)
  end

end
```

Done.

Comment: This code does not make sense. `num` in `initialize` is not used, and `@size` is also never used. Also, this keeps six elements whereas the OP is asking for five.

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for ie: comments.shift if comments.size > 4
    comments.push(value)

Comment: @sawa Thanks for pointing out the mistakes. Updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

If I'm not mistaken, you are using Rails. The "Rails way" is to use an [association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Now you can get the last 5 comments with:

```
@current_user.comments.last(5)
```

If you want to / have to store your comments in an array, you could replace your assignment with something like:

```
comments.push(message).slice!(0...-5)
```

The above adds `message` to the array and removes everything but the last 5 elements. It also works with multiple items:

```
comments.push(message1, message2).slice!(0...-5)
```

Comment: From what do you assert the OP is using Rails?

Comment: From the OP's [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134235/how-to-add-to-a-serialized-array)

Comment: And it's supposition, not assertion.

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby arrays are dynamic, which means they grow bigger the more data you put into it, and Ruby does not provide a built in for what you want. So if you want a ring-type data structure, you have to implement it yourself.

A quick and dirty of a ring-array implementation could go something like:

```
class Ring
    def initialize(s)
      @r = []
      @r.fill(nil, 0, 5)
      @s = s
    end
    def push(e)
       @r.shift
       @r.push e
    end
 end
```

Comment: Arrays in Ruby are dynamic, so if you want a ring buffer type thing, you need to either implement it yourself, or get one from someone else.

Comment: @spuggy if you don't want to store 10,000 messages in the array, just don't do it...

Answer (score 0):

```
if comments.size < 5 then
    comments << new_comment
else 
    oldest = comments.sort{|e| e.date}.last
    if oldest.date < new_comment.date then # comment is newer?
        comments[comments.index(oldest)] = new_comment #swapping
    end
end
```