# Add email model that allows for one primary and multiple secondary email addresses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, model

In Rails, I want to create a model email that allows for polymorphic associations from different people, say 'users' and 'admins' so that they 'has_one' primary_email and 'has_many' secondary_emails.

Is there a way to do this under one model called Email?

I was thinking of creating an Email model that has a column for primary_email:text and another column secondary_email:array (of emails).

I feel like there is a better way to do this though.

**EDIT**

Now I am thinking of creating a simple Email model with just one email column (and emailable_id and emailable_type columns as well). Then User will "has_many" emails. Now I am a little confused as to how the relations work. Right now a user already has an email column. Can anyone think of a way to consider this their primary email in the User model. Then if the user already has a primary email, create a secondary email.

To be clear
I want all of the emails to be part of the Email model, and the distinction between primary and secondary emails to be made in the User model.

Can anyone think of a way to do something like that?

Thanks!

Comment: So nothing changes other than being primary or a secondary email?  In which case you should look into single table inheritance

Answer (score 0):

If I were to do this, I would go for an array attribute using the `serialize` method. (See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134235/how-to-add-to-a-serialized-array) and [this tut](http://amberonrails.com/storing-arrays-in-a-database-field-w-rails-activerecord/).)

Remember that `has_many` is an association between two models, so it is definitely *not* possible to use it with only one model. But there is also nothing wrong with creating a second model for storing only one email, and using `has_many`