# How can I get rails to automatically populate a dynamically generated form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, dynamicform

Let's say I have a model

```
class A < ApplicationRecord
  serialize :vals, Array
end
```

which stores an array of values. How can I dynamically populate a list of form values? My first guess was to write

```
<%= @a.vals.each_with_index do |v, i| %>
  <%= f.text_field :hints %>
<% end %>
```

but this is giving me errors.

Comment: Broadly speaking, `A.vals` is wrong because you are declaring `vals` as a serialized field, which would be accessed from an _instance_ of `A`, not the class object. `serialize :vals, Array` looks wrong, because `Array` isn't a serializer class. Won't be able to get more specific than that without more information. What is the `form_for` or `form_tag` for the example form? How is `vals` initialized?

Comment: You should add the errors to your question. And, what @AdamLassek said, too. (Although, `serialize :vals, Array` may be correct based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134235/how-to-add-to-a-serialized-array) - not 100% sure.)

Comment: @AdamLassek serialize :vals, Array works

Comment: @AdamLassek thank you for pointing out that typo.

Comment: @user1876508 you're right, it looks like `serialize` will default to YAML if you give it a non-coder class, and then it will pass the deserialized value into `Array.new`.

Comment: @AdamLassek Interesting. Is this behavior documented?

Comment: @user1876508 the [official documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-serialize) _sort of_ discusses it, but it's not entirely clear what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Submitting this form

```
<%= form_for @a do |f| %>
  <% @a.vals.each do |val| %>
    <%= f.text_field :vals, value: val, multiple: true %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

passes `"a"=>{"vals"=>["first", "second", "third"]}` in the params to the controller.

As mentioned in the comments, you want to look at the `vals` from an instance of `A` not the class `A`.

Note about the `serialize` (more for the comments saying it looks wrong) I had never used it, that `serialize :vals, Array` seems to be working for me

```
A.create(vals: ['hint 1', 'hint 2']); A.last.vals
#   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
#   SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO ... [["vals", "---\n- hint 1\n- hint 2\n"]...
#   (0.6ms)  COMMIT
#   A Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "as".* FROM "as" ORDER BY "as"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
# => ["hint 1", "hint 2"]
```

Comment: Also, I made a typo for the instance of A.

Comment: After inspecting the source of `serialize` more closely, it appears that passing a non-coder class like `Array` causes it to default to `YAMLColumn`, which passes the deserialized data into `Array.new`. So there was some magic here that confused me.