# How can I retrieve an array stored in postgresql via Sequel as an array?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel

I have a ruby script, a postgres database and I use the Sequel gem to connect to the database.

I want to store and retrieve records, where some of the column values are arrays (set to `text[]` as data type). I therefore load the `pg_array` extension for sequel.

I create a hash `{id: 1, key1: Sequel.pg_array(["lorem ipsum", "caesar", "quidquid id est, timeo danaos"])}`

I can insert the hash through `table.insert hash` and it creates the correct looking record.

```
 id |                          key1                          
----+--------------------------------------------------------
 1  | {"lorem ipsum",caesar,"quidquid id est, timeo danaos"}
```

Based on this favourable result I deduce that the `database`, the `sequel gem` and the `pg_array` extension are all set up correctly.

However, when I retrieve the record via `sequel` again with `advisers.where(id: 1).all` I get this

```
[{:id => 1, :key1 => "{\"lorem ipsum\",caesar,\"quidquid id est, timeo danaos\"}"}]
```

The value of `:key1` is returned as `String`. I can't make heads or tails of the documentation. Does anyone have a way to turn this directly back into the array it started out as: `["lorem ipsum", "caesar", "quidquid id est, timeo danaos"]`?

Much appreciated from a total newbie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually handled when you load the `pg_array` extension into your `Sequel::Database` instance.  Maybe you just loaded the `pg_array` extension file without loading it into your `Sequel::Database` instance.  You might have done:

```
Sequel.extension :pg_array
```

instead of:

```
DB.extension :pg_array
```

You need to load the `pg_array` extension into your `Sequel::Database` instance for retrieved values to be array-like objects and not strings.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19134814/297087), add following in your model

```
serialize :key1, Array
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I am not using Rails, so I'm not sure this applies. I can create a model, but it will not be able to inherit from ActiveRecord::Base as per your link.

Comment: as expected I get the following error following your solution: `(undefined method 'serialize' for Adviser:Class)`. This is because my model cannot inherit from ActiveRecors, as I don't use rails in this setup.